# Why set_model method in PyGtk duplicate the value of the first column at the third column?

Tags: python, user-interface, interface, treeview, pygtk

I'm using PyGtk to display some string information in a treeview.
Here goes my code:

```
def create_table(self):
    self.mainbox = gtk.ScrolledWindow()
    self.mainbox.set_policy( gtk.POLICY_AUTOMATIC, gtk.POLICY_AUTOMATIC)
    self.window.add( self.mainbox)

    model = gtk.ListStore( str, str, str)
    self.treeview = gtk.TreeView(model=None)

    col = gtk.TreeViewColumn( "Element")
    self.treeview.append_column( col)
    cell = gtk.CellRendererText()
    col.pack_start( cell, expand=False)
    col.set_attributes( cell, text=0)

    col = gtk.TreeViewColumn( "Test")
    self.treeview.append_column( col)
    cell = gtk.CellRendererSpin() 
    col.pack_start( cell, expand=False)
    col.set_attributes( cell, text=1)

    col = gtk.TreeViewColumn( "Command")
    self.treeview.append_column( col)
    cell = gtk.CellRendererSpin()
    col.pack_start( cell, expand=False)
    col.set_attributes( cell, text=0)

    cell = gtk.CellRendererCombo()
    self.mainbox.add( self.treeview)
    self.mainbox.set_size_request( 500, 260)
    self.mainbox.show()
    self.vbox.pack_start(self.mainbox, expand=False, fill=True, padding=0)
```

Then, I created a method to fill the treeview after an event button. The call:

```
 def populate_treeview_button(self):
    button = gtk.Button(label='Populate Table')
    button.connect("clicked", self.create_model)
    self.vbox.pack_start(button, expand=False, fill=True, padding=0)
```

And the method (I receive a list of dicts at table_information attribute where the key is an element(string) and the value a list with 2 strings):

```
def create_model(self, beats_me_param):
    model = gtk.ListStore( str, str, str)

    elements = []
    tests = []
    commands = []

    table_information = self.get_organized_table()

    for i in table_information:
        for dicts in i:
            for element in dicts.keys():
                elements.append(element)

    for i in table_information:
        for dicts in i:
            for value in dicts.values():
                tests.append(value[0])
                commands.append(value[1])


    for i in range(len(elements)):
        model.append([elements[i], tests[i], commands[i]])            

    self.treeview.set_model(model)
```

When I saw the result at my treeview, I got at third column the same value of the first column and of course they are different. Image bellow:
[image: table]

I changed the order of elements in the "append" moment and same occurs, the value changes but the changed value is repeated at the third column. What's going wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was because I set the same index to the third and first column.

```
col = gtk.TreeViewColumn( "Command")
self.treeview.append_column( col)
cell = gtk.CellRendererSpin()
col.pack_start( cell, expand=False)
col.set_attributes( cell, text=2)
```

The right way.